# Calculating percentage overlap in graphical modeller

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, qgis-modeler

Can anyone help me calculate the percentage overlap of a polygon with multipoint attributes (I.e fragmented pieces of polygon overlapping) in graphical modeller?

I need to calculate the area of my original polygon, then the area of the overlapping polygon (all the parts/attributes), then add A final filed to calculate the percentage overlap.

In an ideal world I would also like to count the sum total over overlapping parts as another total.

The final end product should end up on a single line with the attributes from the original polygon, the percentage area overlapped and the number of overlapping attributes.